# How to get all fields of related object Django

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Checklist(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     related_name='details')
    fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    fieldA_Check= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fieldB = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    fieldB_Check= models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Client(models.Model):
    client_fieldA = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    client_fieldB = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    client_fieldC = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Now I trying to change Client instance fields values via Checklist using following code:

```
@login_required
def create_order(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(CheckList, id=pk)
    form = myForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Test message')
        return get_PDF_order(request, pk)
    return render(request, 'templates/create_order.html', {'form': form})
```

here is my form:

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_fieldA', 'client_fieldB', 'client_fieldC')

        widgets = {
            'client_fieldA': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'client_fieldB': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'client_fieldC': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

And it works but only once. Data saved and I get a pdf file with this data, but subsequent attempts do not change anything. The field value still the same. I'm guessing that it is because I working with the Checklist instance but not Client. So, my questions are: 1) How I can get an access to all Client fields (a queryset of all Client fileds) via Checklist? 2) Although my code is incorrect - why does it work (once)? I mean why does it save first time?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How's your form defined?

Comment: Hi, Christophe! Updated post with the form Model. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not very sure, I did not use the `instance` that much, but how could you initiate a form based on a model and specify an instance based on another one? If you have the ChekList ID, you should look for the related Client ID then use a Client instance

Comment: Yeah Christophe, I believe that we could)) I guess it's possible to make a query from one instance model to another and get all values from it via existing related name but I don't have skill enough to build it correctly (Question #1 in my topic). Anyway thank you for your effort so far

Comment: could you try this: `form = myForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance.client_name)`? After all, your instance is a check list and you should be able to reach related client like this

Comment: Oh maaan! It's successfully done! You are a person with big heart. Thank you very much!)))

Comment: You're welcome. But it confirms that the instance needs to be the same type of the model form ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formalize the answer, the `instance` is actually an instance of the model the form is based on. Thus, in your case, you *cannot* pass a `CheckList` instance to a form based on `Client`
Anyway, as far as you have the CheckList id, you can easily obtain the Client, and the code for your view will be:

```py
@login_required
def create_order(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(CheckList, id=pk)
    form = myForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance.client_name)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Test message')
        return get_PDF_order(request, pk)
    return render(request, 'templates/create_order.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass it always the same instance, so what happens is that you are probably overwriting the same record over and over.
I would recommend you to split this using the django-provided generic class-based views [CreateView and UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

Stop reinventing the wheel, use class-based views. It'll pay off big time in the long term.

Comment: Hi, Beikeni! Thanks for your help. Just to make clear some things...1) Well, do you mean overwriting by old data even if I put in to form new data? Somehow it takes old data from DB and overwriting again by? Please note, it's not overwriting by new values when I call method again. 2) I'm totaly agree with you regarding Class Based views - it's nice and easy aproach, BUT only when you need some standart staff such as: create, retrive, update instance - DIRECTLY and so on, if we need something more then we need "reinventing the wheel" via CBV.